# AnyLogic: How to create more agents of the same type with distribution?

Tags: anylogic

I'm simulating an office, where an order gets converted to packing-orders.
So after processing (delay) one agent, it should create multiple agents of the same type.
The number of agents is depending on a distripution.

I've tried to use triangular() in the "split-block" or "inject(triangular(...))" but that wont work.

Comment: if you are using a split block just use triangular(1,2,3) as the number of copies... easy

Comment: I've tried that and I get the error "Description: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int."

Comment: (int)round(triangular(1,2,3)...

Answer (score 0):

As written from **Felipe** I used (int)round(triangular(1,2,3))